# Want to know the diff among pd.factorize, pd.get_dummies, sklearn.preprocessing.LableEncoder and OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, machine-learning, scikit-learn

All four functions seem really similar to me. In some situations some of them might give the same result, some not. Any help will be thankfully appreciated!

Now I know and I assume that internally, `factorize` and `LabelEncoder` work the same way and having no big differences in terms of results. I am not sure whether they will take up similar time with large magnitudes of data.

`get_dummies` and `OneHotEncoder` will yield the same result but `OneHotEncoder` can only handle numbers but `get_dummies` will take all kinds of input. `get_dummies` will generate new column names automatically for each column input, but `OneHotEncoder` will not (it rather will assign new column names 1,2,3....). So `get_dummies` is better in all respectives.

Please correct me if I am wrong! Thank you!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

These four encoders can be split in two categories:

- Encode **labels into categorical variables**: Pandas `factorize` and scikit-learn `LabelEncoder`. The result will have 1 dimension.
- Encode **categorical variable into dummy/indicator (binary) variables**: Pandas `get_dummies` and scikit-learn `OneHotEncoder`. The result will have n dimensions, one by distinct value of the encoded categorical variable.

The main difference between pandas and scikit-learn encoders is that scikit-learn encoders are made to be used in **scikit-learn pipelines** with `fit` and `transform` methods.

### Encode labels into categorical variables

Pandas `factorize` and scikit-learn `LabelEncoder` belong to the first category. They can be used to create categorical variables for example to transform characters into numbers.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing    
# Test data
df = DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], columns=['Col'])    
df['Fact'] = pd.factorize(df['Col'])[0]
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Lab'] = le.fit_transform(df['Col'])

print(df)
#   Col  Fact  Lab
# 0   A     0    0
# 1   B     1    1
# 2   B     1    1
# 3   C     2    2
```

### Encode categorical variable into dummy/indicator (binary) variables

Pandas `get_dummies` and scikit-learn `OneHotEncoder` belong to the second category. They can be used to create binary variables. `OneHotEncoder` can only be used with categorical integers while `get_dummies` can be used with other type of variables.

```
df = DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], columns=['Col'])
df = pd.get_dummies(df)

print(df)
#    Col_A  Col_B  Col_C
# 0    1.0    0.0    0.0
# 1    0.0    1.0    0.0
# 2    0.0    1.0    0.0
# 3    0.0    0.0    1.0

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
df = DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], columns=['Col'])
# We need to transform first character into integer in order to use the OneHotEncoder
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Col'] = le.fit_transform(df['Col'])
enc = OneHotEncoder()
df = DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(df).toarray())

print(df)
#      0    1    2
# 0  1.0  0.0  0.0
# 1  0.0  1.0  0.0
# 2  0.0  1.0  0.0
# 3  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

*I've also written a more detailed [post](https://www.back2code.me/2017/09/numeric-and-binary-encoders-in-python) based on this answer.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is really clear, so internally, factorize and LabelEncoder works the same way; get_dummies and OneHotEncoder will yield the same result but OneHotEncoder can only handle numbers but get_dummies will take all kinds of input right?

Comment: Internally they do not work the same way since scikit-learn encoders works in two steps `fit` and transform, but they produce the same result. And yes `get_dummies` will take all kinds of inputs.

Comment: Great reply - do you think you could show us a quick comparison performance-wise ? I get the feeling LabelEncoder of Sklearn is significantly slower than Pandas factorizer, but this is just a feeling...

Comment: What should we use nowadays, pd.factorize()  astype('category') or pd.Categorical()? What's the difference?
For example I want to create a kendall correlation matrix of all features and I need to convert the string columns to categorical or factors.