# what is different between fit_transform, transform in sklearn and get_dummies in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

When I do data processing with one-hot-encoding in sklearn and pandas, I have two options:

1st way: train_data uses fit_transform and test_data uses transform only

2nd way: or I can use pandas get_dummies for both

What is differences between them? And do they have the same effects?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to know the diff among pd.factorize, pd.get\_dummies, sklearn.preprocessing.LableEncoder and OneHotEncoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336502/want-to-know-the-diff-among-pd-factorize-pd-get-dummies-sklearn-preprocessing)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, OneHotEncoder and pandas.get_dummies will both create binary variables out of categorical variables. 
for example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["1", "1", "3"], 'B': ["2", "3", "1"],
                'C': [1, 2, 3]})

print(pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=['col1', 'col2']))
```

will print out :

```
C  col1_1  col1_3  col2_1  col2_2  col2_3
0  1     1.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
1  2     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0
2  3     0.0     1.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
```

OneHotEncoder can deal with non-string variables, while get_dummies can't. Also, OneHotEncoder will return an array, not a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Hi, when I try to use get_dummies with non-string variables, it also works. So that's why I don't see any difference between them